# Pegar informaçoes do Header, javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, header

Bom dia, eu preciso pegar o statuscode que retorna no header, depois que executo um POST , gostaria de saber uma maneira de conseguir isto, usando java script
se possível qual a melhor maneira de pegar o status que a api me retorna direto do header?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o objeto `XMLHttpRequest` do próprio javascript, seria da seguinte forma:

```
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {    
        console.log(this.status); //Status Code

        //Successfully
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //TODO
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "ENDPOINT_API", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo um post utilizando o Jquery, você consegue pegar o status no caso de erro. A partir do Jquery 3.0, você faria desta forma:

```js
$.ajax("minha_pagina.php")
  .done(function(data) {
      //Sucesso
      console..log(data);
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      //Erro
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
      alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
})
```

Aqui tem mais informações:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/